# Is it possible to start an activity inside of a try/catch?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-activity, try-catch

I have a service that is suppose to start the android music app, basically making the Music Application pop up on the screen. The way I was trying to do this is:

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    System.out.println("LOGS STARTED");
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    Iterator i = l.iterator();
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    while(i.hasNext()) 
    {
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo)(i.next());
        try 
        {
            CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            Log.w("LABEL", c.toString());
            if(c.equals("Music"))
            {
                System.out.println("HELLO \n");
                                    Intent in = new Intent();
                in.setClassName("com.android.music", "com.android.music.MediaButtonIntentReceiver");
                startActivity(in);
            }
         }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            //Name Not FOund Exception
        }
    }

}
```

The logcat does display Hello, but for some reason, music won't start. But when I move it to another location it does start. Is there a way to do it this way, or do I have to do it another way? I want the music application to pop up once the user clicks the icon. That is why I did the if c.equals("Music") part. The reason why it is inside of the try is because this line:

```
CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
```

would get an error and the quick fix was for it to be surrounded by try/catch statements.

Comment: Just a guess... "com.android.music.MediaButtonIntenrtReceiver" -> "com.android.music.MediaButtonIntentReceiver"

Comment: It's definitely possible. If the music does not start, there will be some other problem...

Comment: @Thomas I don't want the music to start, I just want the app to pop up, but it won't pop up.

Comment: try catch is not a "quick fix".  It is how you control expected and unexpected errors.  Chances are that you are getting an error with you are hiding because you do nothing in your catch block.  Either put a breakpoint on your catch and inspect the exception or remove it and check logcat for the error.  Then edit your question with the exact problem.

Comment: `try-catch` block does not have anything to do with the rest of your code. As dougcunha said, you have a typo on the `in.setClassName("com.android.music", "com.android.music.MediaButtonIntenrtReceiver");` line - `IntenrtReceiver` should be `IntentReceiver`

Comment: @Tomas it was just a typo on here.

Comment: @dougcunha i fixed the typo, but it was just on here, not in my code.

Comment: @Simon I tried removing the try/catch and it wouldn't run so I couldn't get the error from the logcat. When I inserted the breakpoint on the catch, the logcat didn't change. When I removed the catch, it wouldn't let me run.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it wouldn't run" ?  What was the error?  No one can help you when you make meaningless reports like that.  You could also add e.printstacktrace() to the catch block, so you will know if the exception being caught is due to a programmer error, rather than a true runtime oddity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lots of misunderstanding here about Intents, the difference between Activities and BroadcastReceivers, and the general way Android is set up for things like this. Let's see if we can clear some of that up. :)

You've created an Intent and you're trying to target it at a specific package then call `startActivity`. But you're trying to target the component `com.android.music.MediaButtonIntentReceiver`, which is not an Activity. Calling `startActivity` with this Intent will likely fail.

It's worse than just that though. Even if you had the precise Activity name to send an intent to for the `com.android.music` package, what about users who have a different music app installed? Many OEMs ship their own variant of a music player on devices, which means explicitly targeting that package name will fail on their devices. Google Play Music as shipped on Nexus devices for example uses the package name `com.google.android.music`, not the package you have specified above.

Filtering based on matching the localized app label string is also going to cause you problems. You're looking for an app simply titled "Music", but this string will vary based on both the specific music app and locale. Google Play Music uses the string, "Google Play Music", for example, and "Music" translated into other languages won't match this exact string either.

Finally, you're only looking through running app processes with the ActivityManager. This is going to cause you problems because what if the app isn't currently running at the time? Android can kill an app process in the background for resources and the user should not need to be aware of this. You're writing code that will break unexpectedly for your users.

So what can you do?

Intents are made to be general. Instead of scraping the running process list for a specific package with a specific human-readable label string, tell Android what you're trying to do semantically. You want to start the Music app.

```
Intent musicIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(musicIntent);
```

Going line by line, what we've done here is tell Android that:

- We want to launch a "main" action rather than something more specialized
- We want it to be an Activity that the user would normally launch from the Launcher (home screen)
- We want it to be an app that advertises itself as being able to play music
- We want it to launch in a new task, or if a task for that app already exists, bring it to the front.

Now in fewer lines of code we've managed to accomplish this in a more general way that is more resistant to edge cases and will also automatically follow the user's preference of music app. (If there is more than one app that matches the Intent, the user will be asked which one they want to start and will have an opportunity to set that as the default for next time.)

All that said, you also mentioned you're starting an Activity from a Service. It's generally considered poor user experience design if this happens out of nowhere instead of in response to an action taken by the user, so keep that in mind.

Comment: +1(vote) i agree with you @adamp.Thanks so much for sharing this detailed information.